# keyboard / mouse not working via python in MacOS Ventura 13.1 (22C65)

Tags: python-3.x, keyboard, mouse, macos-ventura

This is the first time I use the keyboard and the mouse via python and I am not sure whether it is not working or that I am doing something wrong.

I have imported: pywhatkit & pynput & pyautogui

KEYBOARD:
all of the above are running fine up to the moment I want to let them press enter (or any other key).

Mouse:
I can find the location of mouse via pyautogui 'x, y = pyautogui.position()' and this works fine and the x and y seems logical. However, changing the position via one of the above modules as well as clicking is not working.

It feels like that I am not authorised to make changes via python or something. The code isn't to hard and should be fine with the examples online. Is there a slider in MacOS that I need to switch?

One other thing that I found strange during this processes. when importing mouse it gives me this error:

---

```
import mouse
```

File "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mouse/**init**.py", line 56, in <module>
raise OSError("Unsupported platform '{}'".format(_platform.system()))
OSError: Unsupported platform 'Darwin'

---

That is strange due to the fact that 'platform.system()' returns 'Darwin'. So I have looked into the file and indeed Darwin is not part of the code (see code below). However when I google it, I find versions that do support this module (https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/master/keyboard/mouse.py). Why is my version not supporting MacOS?

Looking in this file it starts with the below (above is all text that's why it is as far down as line 56):

---

version = '0.7.1'

import time as _time

import platform as _platform
if _platform.system() == 'Windows':
from. import _winmouse as _os_mouse
elif _platform.system() == 'Linux':
from. import _nixmouse as _os_mouse
else:
raise OSError("Unsupported platform '{}'".format(_platform.system()))

---

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

System Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Accessibility -> Terminal slider